# getting "invalid quoted string" while updating calendar event

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google calendar API with my ASP.NET application, and it was working fine till morning but suddenly I was getting lots of exception from Google calender

```
“The specified value is not a valid quoted string”
```

I am not sure if Google has changed any service from their end. Please help in this regards, it is really creating problem on server. Currently I am using the Google calendar V3 having DLL version as 1.6.0.67 and I want to update my code for their new DLL and not getting proper documentation for this. Please hep if any both knows about the documentation.

Comment: I also started getting this problem today. It looks like the problem is on Google's end.

Comment: Take a look in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649831/updating-calendar-event-giving-error-the-specified-value-is-not-a-valid-quoted. We are working on this one. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It should work now. There was a problem in the Calendar API and how it set the etag property. I'm working on a change (https://codereview.appspot.com/96320045/) to make the library more robust and avoid throwing errors in this case.